# Open alertDialog inside a Tabview which is inside another tabview

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-alertdialog, android-tablelayout, android-tabactivity

I have a `tab view` inside that `tab view`, another `tab view` inside that tab view`, and a alert box. When I try to open it my application gets force closed.

[image]

But that same `AlertDialog` is working fine on first tab view.

Comment: please post your logcat error

Comment: Actually I am working on a terminal so I can't see error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be making the mistake with passing the context to the alertdialog this is a very common mistake.

you must pass the context as getParent() not "this" beacause working with tabs it's not your activity that's running it's the parent activity displaying the contents of your activity I could have helped you better if you had posted some code.

Comment: Yes I put this.Please tell me what should I put over there. `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

Comment: put AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());

Comment: Yes Thank it's done.
I should do AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getParent());

Comment: But sorry I can't up vote you becoz I don't have 15 Reputation